# Reporting on status change in JIRA

Tags: jql

A main concern is to have access to a report on the time taken from one status to another ie time taken to handle an issue ( time taken from Open--> Assigned, In Progress --> Resolved)

At the moment, you have to go into each single issue to have the information and it is impossible to collate all this.I need to fetch the data by running the JQL (if possible), i know this is possible from SQL but every time we can can't go back and run the query.

Answer (score 0):

It could be d with ScriptField provided by ScriptRunner plugin. Are you able to use it?

Comment: _Are you able to use it?_. This is more a comment than an answer. I appreciate you cannot comment yet but if you don't the answer I would refrain from answering.

Comment: we dont want to use any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

More one option: free plugin [JSU](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities/server/overview) provids new tab into issue view with status changes and time between transitions.

Comment: we dont want to use any plugin.